# Showing dynamic links inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, how can I show a link that is generated on the fly inside a table?

I will have the link stored in my database, but I want it to be shown by a name and then take me to the correct link accordingly.

I have an array of strings like `[ {Name1:Link1} ]` stored, and I want it to be shown inside the table as `Name1` linking to `Link1`.

Please tell me how to do so.

Comment: You will need to provide more information, code examples. Too hard to work out what you are saying. What stack are you using. Where is the array stored....etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store them in a (object) map instead of an array.

```
var linksMap = {
    'google': 'http://google.com',
    'stackoverflow': 'http://stackoverflow.com',
    'jquery': 'http://jquery.com'
};
```

Then, assuming that you've the following table,

```
<table id="links">
    <tr><td>google</td></tr>
    <tr><td>stackoverflow</td></tr>
    <tr><td>jquery</td></tr>
</table>
```

you can use the following jQuery script to create links and put them in the cells:

```
$('#links>tbody td:nth-child(1)').each(function() {
    var $td = $(this);
    var name = $td.text();
    var link = linksMap[name];
    var $a = $('<a>').attr('href', link).text(name);
    $td.html($a);
});
```