# I have a jqgrid table in which I want to add dynamic links for certain number of keywords in the text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a jqgrid table in which I want to add dynamic links for certain number of keywords in the text. I have keywords as key-value pair. I went through one example in [Showing dynamic links inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765676/showing-dynamic-links-inside-a-table) , it is working with normal table data but not with jqgrid table data. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var linksMap = {
  'google': 'http://google.com',
  'stackoverflow': 'http://stackoverflow.com',
  'jquery': 'http://jquery.com'
  };

jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
$('#jqGrid>tbody td:nth-child(1)').each(function() {
var $td = $(this);
var name = $td.text();
var link = linksMap[name];
var $a = $('<a>').attr('href', link).text(name);
$td.html($a);
});
</script>
```

When using this code with jqgrid, table gets disappearing. Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: You can use a custom formatter. Check the docs for free-Grid how to do this

Comment: please can you show me any example for that.